# do we have nextval kind of sequence function in cassandra ? If not how to handle it?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Me working with apache Cassandra 3.x version for my PoC.
I have case where I need to generate Ids of Items sequentially i.e. Unique ids.
In SQL we have Sequence function called NextVal  to generate next unique id.

Do we have something like that in cassandra ? If not how to achieve it ?

Comment: Can you have missing values (gaps)? Counter columns may give you what you need

Comment: @Jim Wartnick , no there should be any missing values..